# Chrome automatically groups my extension context menu items under one parent, how can I prevent that?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Here is the code:

```
const fileTypes = ["Jack", "John", "Mary"];
chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(() => {
    fileTypes.forEach(type => {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            id: type,
            title: type.toUpperCase(),
            contexts: ["link"],
            targetUrlPatterns: ["https://www.mywebsite.com/*/*/*", "https://mywebsite.com/*/*/*"]
        });
    });
});
```

However, when I test it, the context menu items are automatically grouped into one, under my extension's icon like this:

[image]

How can I split them? So that I don't need to click twice to execute the callback functions?

Thanks

Comment: There's no way. One extension can only create one top-level entry.